# Forming differential equations from words

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider two tanks, A and B, each holding 200 litres of water. A pipe pumps
water from tank A to tank B at a rate of 5 l/min. At the same time another
pipe pumps liquid from tank B to tank A at the same rate. At time $t=0$, $x_0$
kg of a chemical X is dissolved into tank A, and tank B has $y_0$ kg of the same
chemical X dissolved into it.

I got 
$$\begin{align*}\frac{dx}{dt}&=-x_0\frac{t}{40}+y_0\frac{t}{40}\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=-y_0\frac{t}{40}+x_0\frac{t}{40}\end{align*}$$

Is this right? I know it seems easy but I've seen some say the signs are the other way around.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem, assume that the water in the tanks is well-mixed.

What this means is at time $t$, the concentrations of chemicals X and Y in tank A is not static, it changes as water from the other tank goes in.

Your current equation

1. doesn't specify what $x$ and $y$ represent as a function of $t$
2. says "the change in $x$ is some constant depending on $x_0$ and $y_0$"
3. which doesn't depend on the current value of $x$ or $y$ at all